# sqlite use 2 columns as lower bound and higher bound, efficient lookup?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'd like to create a table with 2 cols named `lo` and `hi` which are then integer.
The number of raw can be quite big.
Then I'd like find (select) all the rows where

```
lookup>=lo && lookup<hi
```

I guess there must be some trick to make the lookup efficient.

Comment: Take a look at the `Between` operator.

Comment: Are the columns indexed?  Without indexing the engine performs a full table scan searching all rows until criteria is met.  With an index the system is able to cut the work down to less I/O intensive search.  So what's the execution plan look like?  That will tell us if an index is being used. https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: Yes I was thinking that some index is needed, may be on the 'lo' col, so at least this search can be fast, but I was wondering can we have a second index on the 'hi' ? Also indeed the table data is entered in the way that make sure lo<=hi

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use more than one index per table in a query.

SQLite has multi-column indexes, but at most one column can use a less/greater than comparison.

You have to index one of the columns.
Choose the one where the comparison is more likely to exclude more rows from the result.

See the documentation:
[Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html)
[The Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html)
[The Next-Generation Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html)
[EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: (In the answer itself!)

Answer (score 0):

I did this

```
create table d.r (l integer check (l<h) , h integer , primary key(l,h))
explain query plan select * from d.r  where l>=5 and 5<h

0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE r USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_r_1 (l>?)

select * from d.r  where l>=5 and 5<h
1|6
1|7
2|8
2|9
3|6
4|6
4|7
4|8
5|6
5|8
5|9
```